# How to get results from a depth request with Neo4J and the java-rest-binding?

Tags: java, rest, neo4j

I have no problem with this cypher request :

```
MATCH user-[r:OWE_TO*]->final 
WHERE user.name="toto" AND user.name <> final.name 
AND r[0].value=r[length(r)-1].value       
RETURN  final.name;
```

My results are what I expect but when I use the same with the [java-rest-binding](https://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding) I only receive the first result. I suppose my problem is about the REST response. 
How could I manage to get all my return nodes with this wrapper ? (I have not planned to switch to the spring-rest-client neither to the embedded in this project)

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect the nodes and send the result as an Array.

```
MATCH user-[r:OWE_TO*]->final 
WHERE user.name="toto" AND user.name <> final.name 
AND r[0].value=r[length(r)-1].value       
RETURN  collect(final.name) as finalnames;
```

Comment: Thank you that should be enough for what I need !